# Suggested edit review: rejected by community?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I reviewed a suggested edit to a post today that made valuable changes to a post. I decided to accepted the suggest edit.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4831

Half an hour later, the edit was reviewed by "[Community ♦](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)" and rejected. In the same minute, a user rejected the edit, only to make the exact same edits himself (minus a tag-edit).

1. How can a suggested edit be rejected by "Community ♦". I always thought you needed to be logged in and have sufficient reputation to review suggested edits?
2. Rejecting a suggested edit and then making the same edit yourself seems strange to me. If anything, it discourages relative new users that see their efforts being "stolen" to participate in moderating the site. There is an "accept and edit" button if you feel the need to make minor improvements to a suggested edit, why not use it?

Comment: As the user who suggested the edit, thank you for asking this.

Comment: I think sentryRaven selected to make an additional edit and didn't mark the existing edit as helpful.

Comment: Perhaps there was no other way to reject the added tag?

Comment: @SQB It might have been my mistake entirely. I wanted to partially take your edits, but I did not like the edit made to the flight number. Guess I really just hit the wrong button, my apologies.

Comment: @SentryRaven no prob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good explanation of the edit process here: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

As Federico pointed out, there have been changes to the process since then: [Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039)

It appears that in this case, when the response was "Reject and Edit", that was recorded as a rejection by Community, and then the edit by the user that made the review. The "Reject" part means that the original edit does not appear in the revision history.

If a reviewer is going to keep most or all of the original changes, they should really choose "Improve and Edit". The "Reject" implies that the reviewer is going to make significant changes to the intent of the edit.

Comment: @SQB that is done with the review queue that appears when you get enough reputation

Comment: @SQB What I'm saying is that the explanation seems to say that SentryRaven's history should only show an "Edit" on that question, but instead it says "Reject and Edit".

Comment: `it appears that the reviewer marked the original edit as "not helpful."` I think that it intrinsic in the "**Reject** and edit" option. For marking it as helpful there is the "Improve edit" option. The guide does not reflect the [most recent changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)

Answer (score 5):

For understanding when and why the Community ♦ user accepts or rejects edits see:

[Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-%E2%99%A6-user-approve-and-reject-edits)